# How do i fetch the text from div tag and print in one line

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

`//div[@id='Container']/div/div[2]` -This line gives me the following code:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 25%;" xpath="1">
<span class="dxeBase_Office2010Silver field-fnt" id="Version" style="color:#000000 !important;">
Version
</span>
9.1.2.170
</div>
```

How do i print "Version is 9.1.2.170" in one line.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the text **Version is 9.1.2.170** you can use:

- Using *Java* and *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span[@class='dxeBase_Office2010Silver field-fnt' and @id='Version']/..")).getText());
  ```
- Using *Python* and *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/span[@class='dxeBase_Office2010Silver field-fnt' and @id='Version']/..").text)
  ```